# Why are translates of travelling waves again travelling waves?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

A travelling wave solution of a PDE or ODE is a solution that depends on the single variable $\xi=x-ct$.

For example consider the PDE
$$
u_t=u_{xx}+f(u)-w,~~~w_t=\epsilon (u-\gamma w).~~~~~(1)
$$
Then, a travelling wave $(u(\xi), w(\xi)$ satisfies
$$
-cu_{\xi}=u_{\xi\xi}+f(u)-w,~~~~~-cw_{\xi}=\epsilon (u-\gamma w).~~~(2)
$$

> > Now: Why is any translate $(u(\xi-\xi_0), w(\xi-\xi_0))$ with $\xi_0\in\mathbb{R}$ a travelling wave, too?

If we express the original PDE (1) not in coordinates $t$ and $x$ but in coordinates $t$ and $\xi=x-ct$, then we get
$$
u_t=u_{\xi\xi}+cu_{\xi}+f(u)-w,~~~~~w_t= cw_{\xi}+\epsilon (u-\gamma w).~~~(3)
$$

For a travelling wave, we then have. because of (2),
$$
0=u_{\xi\xi}+cu_{\xi}+f(u)-w,~~~~~0=cw_{\xi}+\epsilon (u-\gamma w),
$$

hence, a travelling wave is an equilibria solution for (3).

*Does this help to argue why any translate of a travelling wave is also a travelling wave?*

Comment: The translate is a travelling wave since the PDE is invariant under shifts $x\to x + c$, $t\to t + d$, i.e. the PDE using the shifted coordinates is the same PDE as the original PDE.

Comment: If $(u(\xi),w(\xi))$ is an equilbrium for (3), why then a translate of it, too?

Comment: But whats with the terms $f(u)$ and -w, for example in the first equation?

Comment: Doesn't this all follow immediately by the fact that a travelling wave is an equilibrium of (3) and hence time independent? So it does not matter if we consider $\xi=x-ct$ or $\xi-k=x-c(t-(k/c))$, i.e. the time $s:=t-(k/c)$ instead of $t$?

Comment: It is written: The travelling wave is an equilibrium (time independent) solution of (3). Do not know exactly how this is meant.

Comment: See here https://books.google.de/books?id=-C6eBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA32&lpg=PA32&dq=travelling+wave+solution+time+independent&source=bl&ots=VfQhasdQDC&sig=9vVv7ZzsI5c_jwmLg6OieUcHafM&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjRtbjclLvJAhXFog4KHb0JA5EQ6AEIWDAH#v=onepage&q=travelling%20wave%20solution%20time%20independent&f=false  namely (4.7) and (4.8).

Comment: Yes,not to the original one but to (3). By the way: What does time independent mean in this case for a travelling wave?

Comment: My bad, should have read your post better. Time-independent here just means that the solution can be written solely in terms of $\zeta$. The PDE given can be though of as a PDE in the two independent coordinates $\zeta$ and $t$ and it's in that sense that it's time-independent. But since $\zeta$ for the case we are interested in is really related to $x,t$ via $\zeta = x - ct$ it's not time-indpendent as you would normally think.

Comment: Sorry, did not get that. To my understanding time independent means that $t$ does not play a role. So it does not matter if we consider $\xi=x-ct$ or $x-ct-k=x-cs$ with $s=t-(k/c))$. So this is - to my opinion - the reason why we can say that a translate is an equilibrium of (3), too and therefore a travelling wave for (1).  - - Without this I do not see the reason since I then have other arguments, for example, $f(u(\xi-k))$ instead of $f(u(\xi)$ and I do not see why this should play no role.

Comment: OK. Lets go back to the definition: "A solution $u(t,x)$ of a PDE is a travelling wave if we can write $u(t,x) = f(x-ct)$ for some function $f$". You agree with this? Do you see that this is not time-independent in the form you mention above?

Comment: No, unless you mean that it is not time independent since t appears in it explicitly.

Comment: The PDE where the time-independent concept comes from is an abstraction. We know that $\zeta = x - ct$, but lets us just consider the PDE $u_t = u_{\zeta\zeta} + \ldots$ like it was any other PDE and $\zeta$ was just a normal spatial coordinate independent of $t$. From *this* point of view the solution $u$ is time-independent so the solution can be written $u = f(\zeta)$ independent of $t$. *However* in the picture we started with we have $\zeta = x-ct$ so this means that $u = f(x-ct)$ so the solution of the problem we started with is *not* time-independent.

Comment: I guess I now understand what you mean. A general solution of (3) is of the form $u(t,\xi)$ (here t appears as an argument) but a travelling wave is a solution of (3) of the form $u(\xi)$, i.e.  $t$ does not appear as an *argument*. Nonethelss, $t$ appears indirectly, namely in $\xi$. - - So in fact, it DOES dependent on $t$. - - - Right? Coud you then explain again why the original PDE (1) is invariant under translates? I still do not see it, I am sorry. I am putting in different arguments in f and w for example, how do I know that for this shifted arguments $u(\xi)$ is still a solution.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it. I wanted to use the equilibrium property to argue that a translate is also a travelling wave but I think that was no good idea. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we perform the translation $t\to t - t_0$ and $x\to x - x_0$, using that derivatives are translation invariant $\frac{d}{d(x-x_0)} = \frac{d}{dx}$, we get that the PDEs

$$\matrix{u_t(x,t) &=& u_{xx}(x,t) + f(u(x,t)) - w(x,t)\\
w_t(x,t) &=& \epsilon[u(x,t) - \gamma w(x,t)]}$$

transforms into

$$\matrix{\hat{u}_t(x,t) &=& \hat{u}_{xx}(x,t) + f(\hat{u}(x,t)) - \hat{w}(x,t)\\
\hat{w}_t(x,t) &=& \epsilon[\hat{u}(x,t) - \gamma \hat{w}(x,t)]}$$

where I have taken $\hat{u}(x,t) = u(x-x_0,t-t_0)$ and $\hat{w}(x,t) = w(x-x_0,t-t_0)$. This is exactly the same PDEs as we started with. If $\{u(x,t),w(x,t)\}$ is a solution then so is $\{u(x-x_0,t-t_0)$, $w(x-x_0,t-t_0)\}$.  In terms of the $\zeta$ variable this means that if $\{u(\zeta),w(\zeta)\}$ is a solution then (take $\zeta_0 = x_0 - ct_0$) so is $\{u(\zeta-\zeta_0),w(\zeta-\zeta_0)\}$.

In general any PDE/ODE where we have no explicit coordinate dependence have the property of being translation invariant.